# Realm model has no initializers

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using a custom base class for my models to be used with Realm for Swift. This is the class.

```
import RealmSwift

public class ModelBase: Object {
    @objc public var createdAt, updatedAt: Date

    required convenience init() {
        createdAt = Date()
        updatedAt = Date()

        self.init()
    }
}
```

Now, when trying to compile this, Xcode will throw an error

> Class 'ModelBase' has not initializers

However, when I change the initializer function to `required public init()` and then let it call `super.init()`, Realm will start complaining that I need to implement additional initializers. Anyone know how I can fix the first issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use custom initializer with declared `init` parameters, like this:

```
import RealmSwift

public class ModelBase: Object {
    @objc public dynamic var createdAt, updatedAt: Date

    convenience init(_ defaultDate: Date = Date()) {
        self.init()

        createdAt = defaultDate
        updatedAt = defaultDate
    }
}
```

in `convenience init` `self.init()` has to be called before initializing all other properties. Also you need to declare properties as `dynamic` since theirs getters and setters are managed by Realm itself.

or if `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are `Date()` by default you can omit initializer at all by declaring `var`s in class declaration.

```
public class ModelBase: Object {
    @objc public dynamic var createdAt: Date = Date()
    @objc public dynamic var updatedAt: Date = Date()
}
```